# doNotCheckCapabilities property in Weka used with Multiplayer Perceptron

Tags: java, weka

What is **doNotCheckCapabilities** property in Weka used with **Multiplayer Perceptron** and what's its influence on classification result?

" If set, classifier capabilities are not checked before classifier is built (Use with caution to reduce runtime)."
the weki hint is not enough for me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before a classifier is being trained, the provided dataset is tested against its capabilities, i.e., the types of data it can handle, required number of training instances. Depending on the data (eg 10s of 1000s of attributes), these capability tests can take a long time and are also computationally expensive. If you are an expert and you know that your data is in the right format already (or you are currently developing a new algorithm, using a custom datset for testing) then you could disable this check. In general, it is a good idea to leave this check in place to avoid errors or unexpected behavior further down the track.